# find the MLE of $f(x \mid \theta) = \theta(\theta+1) x(1-x)^{(\theta-1)}$

Tags: statistics

$$f(x \mid \theta) = \theta(\theta+1) x(1-x)^{(\theta-1)}$$ if $0 \le x \le 1$ (otherwise $f(x \mid \theta) =0$)

we want to estimate $\theta>0$ from a random sample $X_1 , .... , X_n$.

Use the notation $u = \sum_i \log(x_i)$,  $v = \sum_i \log(1-x_i). $
Find the estimator MLE of $\theta$,use the notation $s$ for the expression $-v/n$. Explain why the estimator ($>0$) is unique.

My attempt :

$$L(\theta)=\theta^n(\theta+1)^n \prod_i x_i(1- x_i)^{(\theta-1)}$$

$$l(\theta) = n \log(\theta) + n \log(\theta+1) +  \sum_i \log(x_i) + (\theta-1) \sum_i \log(1-x_i)$$

$$l'(\theta) = n/\theta + n/(\theta+1) + \sum_i \log(1-x_i)$$

i'm stuck here ... solving $l'(\theta) = 0$

$$n/\theta + n/(\theta+1) + v = 0$$

I think I made some mistakes. Can anyone give me some hints ? 
thank you

Comment: Please use Latex for math formatting

Comment: I've tried to fix the formatting, see if I didn't mess up anything

Comment: nope, thank you 
sorry i don't know how to use Latex yet

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

$$\frac{n}{\theta} + \frac{n}{\theta+1} + v = 0$$

$$n \frac{\theta+1 + \theta}{\theta(\theta+1)}  +v=0$$

$$n (2 \theta+1) + (\theta^2 +\theta)v=0$$

Now only need to solve the cuadratic... and (IMPORTANT!) check that the critical point(s) is the true global maximum (NEVER consider yourself done by blindly solving $l'(\theta)=0$ - think about the fucntion, consider its domain, and the extreme points; MLE is not about finding points where the derivative is zero, it's about finding a global maximum, and the global maximum not always corresponds to a critical point).

Comment: i can't solve this equation ... 
i end up having this form : vθ^2 + θ(v+2n) + n =0, by using the quadratic formula i have :( -(v+2n) + or - sqrt(v^2 + 4n^2) ) / 2v

Comment: Then you have solved it, no?

Comment: i have to use complex numbers, by using the s notation, I have sθ^2 + θ(s-2) - 1 =0, using the quadratic formula i have : (-(s-2) + or - (s-2i)(s+2i))/2s

Comment: I don't think I have it right because i need to use the estimator to compute some values in another question